# Difference between "has" and "is" in the context?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Your explanation is correct, but option C says "has" not "is".

---

My attempt:

**is** means the subject is present and **has** means get the subject.

> Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

---

I'm posting a question on ell.se than cs.se. :) good.

```
In a bottom-up evaluation of a syntax directed definition, inherited attributes can

 1. always be evaluated
 2. be evaluated only if the definition **is** L-attributed
 3. be evaluated only if the definition **has** synthesized attributes
 4. never be evaluated
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understood the question, but I think it was probably **option C** or **C** rather than **C option**.

Comment: @Cardinal, title says itself. I read this comment somewhere "Your explanation is correct, but option C says "has" not "is"." Can you explain the meaning of the comment, please?

Comment: I think you should explain your attempt a little bit more. what do you mean *get the subject*?

Comment: It's really hard to say what the meaning of "has" vs "is" in the context of that sentence, because they have no context in that sentence.  All it tells us is that option C says one and not the other; it tells us nothing about their meaning.  "Has" and "is" could be replaced with "floople" and "blarple" and the sentence would still read just as well.

Comment: We need to know what the options are.  *X Is Y* doesn't automatically mean X is "present" and *X has Y* doesn't necessarily have any meaning overlap with *get*.

Comment: @LawrenceC, post is updated.

Comment: Mithlesh, your question is unclear. If you want a useful answer, provide the context. What do you mean by "my attempt?" No-one can explain the meaning of the comment with knowing what was commented upon. The confusion is worsened by the two series involved: you mention Option C, but the provided list of options is numbered 1...4!